# Does "in" do the same thing as str.contains()?

Tags: python, mode

I'm new to Python but am very confused as to how this code works:

Correct code I don't understand:

[image: screenshot of code that works]

I don't understand how in the function, you can just write ".org' in domain to capture whether the referrer_domain is an organization. I thought you would have to filter via .str.contains() to be able to see if the domain includes .org or .com.

I originally coded:

```
dot_org = data[data['referrer_domain'].str.contains('.org')
dot_com = data[data['referrer_domain'].str.contains('.com')

def domain_type(type):
    if type in dot_org['referrer_domain']:
        return 'organization'
    elif type in dot_com['referrer_domain']:
        return 'company'
    else:
        return 'other'

data['new_column'] = data['referrer_domain'].apply(domain_type)
```

But this ended up labeling all of the rows in the new column I created as "other".

Is anyone able to explain why the code in the picture works, but why the code above doesn't?

Comment: It looks like your `data` variable might be a Pandas dataframe? If so, please always remember to specify that and include the [tag:pandas] tag as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki. Python itself doesn't have dataframes.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp

Comment: Yes, `in` does a string search.  But you probably want `.endswith()` instead.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
Your posted code does not run.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  If you want to know whether `in` does string containment, *try it*.  Alternately, read the documentation.  Don't post tutorial questions to this site: do your research.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you all - I'm really sorry for not doing enough diligence before posting. Learned my lesson here, appreciate all the helpful links and the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not use `type` as a variable name, because it's a reserved word.

Aside from that, there is no `str.contains` method, at least not in plain Python. The official way of checking if a string contains another string is using [the `in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).